# store/retrieve data for browser user for angular 2 application

Tags: angular

In angular 2 application, want to store/retrieve authorization data for browser user for remember authorization functionality.

```
rememberAuthorization(authToken: IAuthToken, user: IAppUser) {
    let data = {
        authToken: authToken,
        user: user
    };
    // here i want to store data
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to store data in the client side. It depends on your requirements.

For example, you can use `Window.localStorage` or `Window.sessionStorage`.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

For more info:

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

If you are writing platform independent angular project (Angular Universal),

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { ... }

rememberAuthorization(authToken: IAuthToken, user: IAppUser) {
  let data = {
    authToken: authToken,
    user: user
  };
   if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
         // here i want to store data
    }

}
```